# mysqli_free_result - select successful, but still getting warning

Tags: mysql

I have a problem whereby I am running a SELECT query that returns a valid result set. I process the results using mysqli_fetch_assoc and then pass the result set to mysqli_free_result, which returns false. I have done a var_dump of the result before and after the call to confirm it is a valid result (seems to be to me - I can access the data I expect to). The query I am running is something like:

```
        select us.user_session_key
            , u.user_key
            , ut.code as user_type
        from    t_user u
                inner join t_user_type ut on u.user_type_key = ut.user_type_key
                inner join t_user_session us
                    on u.user_key = us.user_key
        where   u.email = 'tim.super@en.com'
        and     us.session_id = 'mjsvu6fru3dtfk1bbs59fc8t20'
        and     us.expired_yn = 'N'
        order by 1 desc
```

Var dump of the result object:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(3)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

I am using similar to the following code to process query/result:

```
$result = mysqli_query ( $conn, $sql );
if ($result) {
    var_dump($result);
    if (preg_match('/^[[:space:]]*select/i', $sql) == 1) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $result )) {
            $return_val[sizeof($return_val)] = $row;
        }

        if (!clear_results($result)) {
            print "error: ".$sql;
        }
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(401);
    print $sql . "\n";
    print mysqli_error($conn);
    die("error");
}
function clear_results($result) {
    global $conn;

    if ($result) {
        if (!mysqli_free_result ( $result )) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    while (mysqli_more_results($conn)) {
        mysqli_next_result($conn);
        mysqli_free_result(mysqli_store_result($conn));
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You mean you're passing the result pointer to mysqli_free_result right? Not like an array containing the result set or something? Just want to make sure :) If that's not it, add the relevant code?

Comment: Ah nuts - mysqli_free_result does not return anything according to the manual. I am sure I read somewhere that it returned a boolean! Sorry for wasting your time!